# Child Controls Inside Panel doesn't resize on Form resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display banner image on top of MDI form along with some menus. Menus should display on that banner image at right side's bottom position. To achieve this I followed below steps:

1. Added MDI form
2. Panel (`pnlHeader`) - which backcolor is black to match the image background
3. `Picturebox` to display banner image and added it inside the `pnlHeader`
4. Added menustrip (`dock = none`) in Picturebox as want to display menus on banner image (beside logo)

When I resize the form, picture box image and menustrip doesn't resize even Panel is Dock to Top. Is there any suggestion on this? I cannot provide you code due to security reason.

Comment: Have you anchored your picture box and menu trip to the right?

Answer (score 0):

Basically add a new panel to your current layout.
you will end up with this:

[image: layout]

Thing here is doing the correct anchoring, so this settings should work:

-`Picturebox`: `Anchor:Top, Left, Right`. Just adjust size to your needs.

-`pnlHeader`: `Anchor Top, Left, Right`. Just adjust size to your needs.

-`pnlMenuContainer` (Orange): `Anchor Top, Left, Right.` It should be of same Height of contained MenuBar, because it is just for placing the menubar.

-`MenuStrip`(MenuBar in img): `Dock Top` (or Bottom).

With this layout PictureBox and MenuStrip increase their size as you make your form wider. Actually for the MenuStrip, the panel that contains it is the one that increase it size but as your menuStrip is docked it gets bigger too. Same for the inverse (Making it smaller).

I must apologize in advance for any kind of grammar or spelling error.

Best of luck,